# Is there a way to save a casual mode map selection for reuse?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I usually pick the same maps in casual mode, is there a way to save it so I don't have to select them every time I start Team Fortress 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature got added with the Scream Fortress 2016 Update, the [update notes](http://www.teamfortress.com/post.php?id=25022) read:

Added "Load Saved Settings" and "Save Current Settings" buttons to the Casual mode Map Selection menu

The buttons look like this [image: Map Selection Buttons]

The up-arrow loads your saved selection while the down-arrow saves it.
If you are using a custom hud you might not see those buttons if the hud was not updated in quite some time.

Comment: I just used this feature to get to 142 wins in Powerhouse.  It takes longer to get matched if you only have one map selected, but you still get a match in less than 10 minutes usually.  Very handy.